# How to set priority in laravel mail functionality

Tags: laravel

I am sending one mail from laravel code. I want to add priority in it. But it is not showing. Below is my code. I am using laravel 6 version.

```
 public function build()
    {
        if (! empty($this->attributes['replyTo'])) {
            return $this->from($this->from)
                ->view($this->view)
                ->with($this->with)
                ->subject($this->subject)
                ->replyTo($this->attributes['replyTo']);
        } elseif ($this->attributes) {
            return $this->from($this->from['address'], $this->from['name'])
                ->view($this->view)
                ->with($this->with)
                ->subject($this->subject)
                ->priority($this->attributes);
         } //elseif (! empty($this->with)) {
        //     return $this->from($this->from['address'], $this->from['name'])
        //         ->view($this->view)->with($this->with)
        //         ->subject($this->subject);
        // }

        return view($this->view);
    }
```

Comment: add `$this->attributes['priority'] = 1; // set the priority to 1 (highest)` inside `build function first line`.

Comment: What do you mean by priority? This is *not* a flagged message, this is the order in the mailing queue.

Comment: I want to pass it in Header. It is not the priority of the mailing queue.